# Ruby undefined variable

Tags: ruby

I have a code below:

```
secret_number = 8
user_input = ""

def number_guesser(user_input)
  while user_input != secret_number
    puts "Guess a number between 1 and 10:"
    user_input = gets.chomp

    if user_input != secret_number
      puts "Wrong! Try again."
    else
      puts "You guessed correctly!"
    end
  end
end

number_guesser(user_input)
```

when I tried to run the above program it showed as below:

****undefined local variable or method `secret_number' for main:Object
(repl):211:in`number_guesser'
(repl):221:in `'****

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a local variable like that inside another scope such as a method, it's two different contexts. Instead you need to pass that in if you want to use it.

It's a simple change:

```
def number_guesser(user_input, secret_number)
  # ...
end
```

Then just feed that argument in.

You'll note that `user_input` isn't really necessary as a parameter, you can always initialize and use that locally, so it's actually pointless as an argument.

The pattern to use in that case:

```
loop do
  input = gets.chomp

  # Prompting...

  break if input == secret_number

  # Guessed wrong...
end
```

Comment: Furthermore, `secret_number` is an integer whereas `input` is a string, so you have to convert one or the other.